# Why does this code returns segmentation fault when I try to use binary search to count the number of occurrences of a number in an array recursively?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, binary

```
  int countOccurences(int *array, int start, int end, int n)
   {
    int count=0,mid;
    mid=(start+end)/2;
    if(start==end && array[mid]!=n)
        return count;
    if(array[mid]==n)
        return count+countOccurences(array,mid+1,end,n)+countOccurences(array,start,mid-1,n);
    else if(array[mid]>n)
        return countOccurences(array,start,mid-1,n);
    else if(array[mid]<n)
        return countOccurences(array,mid+1,end,n);
    return count;
}
```

I'm getting correct results for the item that does not belong to the list but my code returns segmentation fault for the items that exists in my array. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: A segmentation fault means that you're trying to access an array with an index that is out of bounds. Check the value of `mid` in your debugger.

Comment: Is `end` the index of the last element or one past it?

Answer (score 1):

The strange part of this code is you never checked whether `start <= end` or not. How will this program terminate? At some point your program will branch into calling the function with improper parameters. Add a check to it. Apparently this is a major flaw in the code. What happens when you access array indices out of bound? It is undefined behavior. This is what you faced.(In your case segmentation fault).